# IsFirstRun Problems

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, clickonce

So I'm trying to detect if the application is first run or not, but for some reason I'm getting a name space error. I'm using the following code:

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {      
        lblUsername.Content = "CIS User: " + username;
        lblbuildVersion.Content = staticinfo.buildVersion;

        if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed && System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsFirstRun)
        {
            //display readme file
        }
    }
```

I've tried typing in `using System.Deployment` but after that there is only the internal option. Can't seem to get this to work. I deploy my work using ClickOnce and the target framework is 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment` class is defined in the System.Deployment.dll assembly. It seems that you have not added a reference to that DLL.

Answer (score 1):

For the IsFirstRun property, you need:
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.**CurrentDeployment**.IsFirstRun